# saving fields from multiple documents to an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose for MongoDB operations in my project. I'm trying to:

- find every document matching query
- create a new object (let's call it `objects`)
- for every document found create a new object inside `objects`
- save fields from found document to created object

And this works just fine. But I also want to:

- for every object saved inside my `objects` find one document matching query in another collection
- if document is found, save fields from it to previously created object `objects` (as new keys)

My code for the second part looks like this:

```
for(var i in objects) {
  if(objects.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    Model.findOne({name: objects[i].name, id: objects[i].id}, function(e, document) {
      if(e) console.error(e);
      if(document) {
        console.log("Found matchind document"); //This is showed for each object, as expected.
        objects[i].newField = document.someData;
        objects[i].evenNewerField = document.someMoreData;
      }
    });
  }
}
console.log(objects); //This shows old data from previous operations, no new data from the for loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not your mongoose usage, you should take a deep look to Javascript scope and asynchronous. In your code when console.log is called, objects is not yet updated.

Comment: I figured that out few minutes ago. How should I do this then?

Comment: I don't really see good way to do that, it's the problem with JavaScript, you can't use for/while everywhere. It may be possible to do what you want with promise or using an event system. But i think the best way is to call your console.log (or whatever you want to do instead) in your callback (so to do it at every iteration). Unless you have something to call only once it's the best way in my opinion

Comment: The point is, I'm rendering a page (Express), so want to call it after for loop finishes. I made it so it's in the loop, but it only calls when loop is executing the last time. It partly works, but it still doesn't give me the result I wanted. I'll accept your answer though, as it points in which way I should search for solution.

Comment: What you can do is simply check in your callback if i is the last element of objects (use length property) and call your render when it's true

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but it doesn't work as expected. I'm close to the solution though, thanks!